# How can I allow users to map their own domain to a subdomain on my Cloudfront site?

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, subdomain, cname-record, amazon-cloudfront

So I run a service where a user can create a site and they get their own subdomain. So if a user has site `a-site-name` their subdomain will be `a-site-name.domain.com`. Some of the users want to be able to have their own domains instead of the subdomain on my domain. I know I should be able to do this with a CNAME record in DNS (so `sub.the-users-domain.com` resolves to `a-site-name.domain.com`). However when I try to do this, I get a 403 from Cloudfront.

To describe my setup:

- Files are served by AWS Cloudfront using an S3 bucket as the origin point.
- Each site `a-site-name` is stored in a folder in the S3 bucket of the same name.
- I have a Lambda@Edge function running so that whenever a request is made to `a-site-name.domain.com/whatever-resource` (wildcard subdomains) it actually resolves to and grabs data from `distribution-id.cloudfront.net/a-site-name/whatever-resource`.

I'm guessing the fact that I'm getting a 403 has to do with the configuration of my Cloudfront deployment or with that Lambda@Edge function. Does anyone have any ideas as to how to change the configuration so that people can just use a CNAME record to use their own domains? I'm lost to be honest.

Comment: Cloudfront needs to know which S3 bucket `sub.the-users-domain.com` points to.  Setting a `CNAME` does not tell it that.

Comment: Suspect you will need to write a lambda script to create the bucket, the domain, and glue everything together.